# MySql - if there is no record, insert multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql

Before asking this question, I already search a lot of entries on Google and StockOverflow. Nothing can fulfil my question.

There are two tables - `group_sale_bonuses` and `members`. I want to check is already there records with `product_id "1"` in the `group_sale_bonuses`.

If not, I want to insert all records from `members` table into `group_sale_bonuses` with `product_id "1"`.

My overall requirement is as follow:

```
IF ((Select count(id) from group_sale_bonuses where product_id = 1) = 0) THEN
    INSERT INTO group_sale_bonuses (member_id, product_id, quantity_counter, credit)  
    SELECT id, 1, 0, 0 FROM members
END IF
```

But this sql causes the errors.

I know there are solutions about `Insert Ignore`, `Where Not Exists`.

But these conditions checking are based on per each record. I have thousands of records in `members` table. I want to make condition checking just one time like in my above sql example.

By the way, I will use this `Sql` in `Php` web application.

Comment: which error you are getting?

Comment: @user790454 the error is - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF ((Select count(id) from group_sale_bonuses where product_id = 1) = 0) THEN ' at line 1

Comment: I don't think you can use IF statements like this directly in a query, at least I could not find anything about this on google. I think you should do it with your web application instead. The only if statement I know is if(condition, thenthis, elsethis)

Comment: You can use Routines but that's just bad for your case.

Comment: @BenBeri I know that I can check this condition in my web application, then, just only two touches to the database. But I just want to know is there any solutions only in Sql.

Comment: Why do you need to check first?

Answer (score 0):

You could just set the code in a `WHERE` clause instead of the `IF`.

```
INSERT INTO group_sale_bonuses(
    member_id, 
    product_id,
    quantity_counter,
    credit) 
SELECT 
    id, 1, 0, 0 FROM members 
WHERE( 
    SELECT 
        count(id) FROM group_sale_bonuses
    WHERE product_id = 1
) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for all product_id's

```
SELECT m.product_id, m.member_id FROM members AS m 
LEFT JOIN group_sale_bonuses AS gsb ON gsb.product_id = m.product_id
WHERE gsb.product_id IS NULL ;
```

You can filter it to a specific product_id by adding to the where clause

```
SELECT m.product_id, m.member_id FROM members AS m 
LEFT JOIN group_sale_bonuses AS gsb ON gsb.product_id = m.product_id
WHERE gsb.product_id IS NULL AND m.product_id = 1;
```

Take a look at this SQLfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8482c/2